# Minus logic implementation not working with spark/scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Minus Logic in `Hive`:

The below (`Hive`)query will return only  records available in left side table ( `Full_Table ft`), but not in both.

```
Select ft.* from Full_Table ft  left join Stage_Table stg where stg.primary_key1 IS  null and stg.primary_key2 IS null
```

I tried to implement the same in `spark`/`scala` using following method ( To support both primary key and composite key ) , But joined result set does not have `column` from right table, because of that not able to apply `stg.primary_key2 IS null` condition in joined result set.

```
ft.join(stg,usingColumns, “left_outer”)  // used seq to support composite key column join
```

Please suggest me how to implement minus logic in spark `scala`.

Thanks,
Saravanan
https://www.linkedin.com/in/saravanan303/

Comment: Like to compare only few key column and like to select all column from both left and right table, But EXCEPT will consider all the column to match which is not expected output. See the Hive query for more details.

Comment: I have fixed the same below join query :      val result = ft.join ( stg, columnList.length
    match {
      case 2 =>   ft(columnList(0)) equalTo stg(columnList(0)) and
        ft(columnList(1))=== stg(columnList(1))
      case 3 =>   ft(columnList(0)) equalTo stg(columnList(0)) and
        ft(columnList(1))=== stg(columnList(1)) and
        ft(columnList(2))=== stg(columnList(2))
      case 1 => ft(columnList(0)) equalTo stg(columnList(0))
    }, "left_outer").where(stg(columnList(0)).isNull)
     .select(targetTable + ".*")
     .unionAll(stg)

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have the same columns you can use `except` method from `DataSet`:

```
fullTable.except(stageTable)
```

If they don't have, but you are interested only on subset of columns that exists in both tables you can first select those column using `select` transformation and than use `except`:

```
val fullTableSelectedColumns = fullTable.select(c1,c2,c3)
val stageTableSelectedColumns = stageTable.select(c1,c2,c3)

fullTableSelectedColumns.except(stageTableSelectedColumns)
```

On other case, you can use `join` and `filter` transformations:

```
fullTable
    .join(stageTable, fullTable("primary_key") === stageTable("primary_key"), "left")
    .filter(stageTable("primary_key1").isNotNull)
```

Comment: Like to compare only few key column and like to select all column from both left and right table, But EXCEPT will consider all the column to match which is not expected output. See the Hive query for more details.  The same can be achieved using below join query :

Comment: As I wrote above, if you want to compare only a few columns and select all, you can use join and filter.